# Proof verification for when considered as a subset of $\mathbb{R^2}$, that is, as a line segment on the $x$-axis in the plane, it is not open.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification

Can I please get feedback on my proof for the problem below? Thank you!

$\def\R{{\mathbb R}}                            
\def\Rhat{{\widehat{\R}}}$

So we know the interval $(0,1)$ is open in $\R$.  Prove that, when considered as a subset of $\R^2$, that is, as a line segment on the $x$-axis in the plane, it is not open.  More specifically, show that the set $(0,1)\times\{0\} \subseteq\R^2$ is not open.

$\textbf{Solution:}$ Let $S = (0,1) \times \{0\}$ is open in $\R^2$. Then, by definition, if we take a ball, say $B(x, r)$ centered at any point $x \in S$ with sufficiently small radius $r>0$, then $B(x,r) \subset S$.

Now, take $x = (\frac{1}{2}, 0), r = \frac{1}{2}.$

Then the ball $\displaystyle{\mathbb{B} ((\frac{1}{2}, 0), \frac{1}{2})}$ is a circle whose center is at $(\frac{1}{2}, 0)$ and radius is $\frac{1}{2}$.

By our assumption as $S$ is open in $\R^2$ and $(\frac{1}{2}, 0)\in S$, therefore, the ball $\displaystyle{\mathbb{B} ((\frac{1}{2}, 0), \frac{1}{2})}$ should entirely lie within $S$ but observe that $\displaystyle{(0,\frac{1}{4}) \in \mathbb{B} ((\frac{1}{2}, 0), \frac{1}{2})}$ while $(\frac{1}{2}, 0)\notin S$, hence a contradiction. Thus, our assumption is not true, that is, the set $S= (0,1) \times \{0\}$ is not open in $\R$

Comment: If you define $B(x,r)$ to be the open ball of radius $r$, then $(0,1/2)$ is not in $B((1/2,0),1/2)$ but $(0,1/4)$ is, which is not in $(0,1)\times \{0\}$, but aside from this your proof is fine

Comment: Under the hypothesis that $S$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$, it is not true that *every* ball $B(x,r)$ is in $S$. But it is true for every *sufficiently small* $r$

Comment: @Mick Thank you for the feedback. I made the edit, is it fine now? Sorry about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"if we take any ball" can't be right.  Balls around points in the open disk with radius $1$ can't meet this prescription -- consider any point in this disk and set the radius of the ball to $1$ million.  It is the case that every point in an open set is the center of an open ball contained in the set (but its radius may have to be small, especially if the point is near the boundary of the set).

To adjust your proof to incorporate this modification, you should show that for all $r>0$, $B((\frac{1}{2},0),r)$ fails to be contained in $S$.

Comment: Yes, it should be shown for any $r>0$, I forgot to write this in my previous comment.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is fine, apart from the typo that Mick already pointed out. Also you probably mean a point like (1/2,1/4), and you meant to write $\notin S$ instead of $\neq S$.

Answer (score 1):

This is meant to supplement Eric Towers' answer...

---

To show that

$\quad (\forall x) \; (\exists B) \, (blah)$

is false show that is negation its true

$\quad (\exists x) \; (\forall B) \, [\text{NOT }(blah)]$